# Nested inline iterators

Tags: iterator, nested, nim-lang

Is it possible to have an inline iterator, which accepts another inline iterator as a parameter? My goal is to make a simple pipeline-like processing and get it unrolled into serial C code. An example which I can't get to work:

```
iterator test2(it: iterator(): int {.inline.}): int =
  for i in it():
    yield i*2
iterator test1(): int =
  yield 10
  yield 20
  yield 30
for i in test2(test1()):
  echo j
```

With the error:

```
test.nim(2, 14) Error: type mismatch: got (int) but expected one of:
iterator items[IX, T](a: array[IX, T]): T
iterator items[](E: typedesc[enum]): E:type
iterator items(a: string): char
iterator items[T](s: Slice[T]): T
iterator items[T](a: openArray[T]): T
iterator items[T](a: seq[T]): T
iterator items[T](a: set[T]): T
iterator items(a: cstring): char
> Process terminated with exit code 256
```

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/4516) in Nim's repository. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

you have 2 options (at least)

1. define your iterator as {.closure.}
2. use templates to wrap the iterator and, which is a little ugly but works:

   ```
   template runIterator(it, exec: untyped): typed =
       block:
           it(myIterator)
           for i in myIterator() :
               exec(i*2)

   template defineTest1(name: untyped): typed =

       iterator `name`(): int {.inline.} =
           yield 10
           yield 20
           yield 30

   template defineTest2(name: untyped): typed =

       iterator `name`(): int {.inline.} =
           yield 5
           yield 10
           yield 15

   template exec(i: int): typed  = echo i

   runIterator(defineTest1, exec)
   runIterator(defineTest2, exec)
   ```

edit:

the idea is to use a template instead of an inline iterator and to inject the code - so there is no second iterator but a template.
maybe this makes it clearer:

```
    template test2(it, yielder, exec: untyped): typed =
        for i in it() :
            let `yielder` {.inject.} = 2 * i
            exec


    iterator test1(): int {.inline.} =
        yield 10
        yield 20
        yield 30

    iterator test1b(): int {.inline.} =
        yield 5
        yield 10
        yield 15

    test2(test1, i):
        echo i

    test2(test1b, i):
        echo i
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second option. Which part represents the `test2` iterator? The `runIterator` does not yield anything.